# Show record through ajax on index page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

wondering if anyone has any tips for learning (i.e. know of a tutorial?) how to have the "show" view remotely load through ajax on an index page, when the link for a view is clicked? I'd like the view to appear beneath the link title.

Best,
Elliot

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, render a partial for the item you want:

```
def show
  @item = Item.get(params[:id])
  respond_with (@item) do |format|
    format.html{ render :partial => 'item' } 
    format.js{ render :partial => 'item', :layout=>false }
  end
end
```

And then using jQuery, you could do:

```
$('a#my_loader').bind('click', function(){ 
  $.ajax({url: "/items/1",
          type: "GET",
          success: function(data) {
            $('#items').append(data);
          }
  });
});
```

You would require an a tag with the id 'my_loader' and a div or ul with the id of 'items' in order to make this work.

Comment: The only thing I'd note is that he wants the partial to appear just below the link title... I'm not sure what `$(this)` would refer to in the context of the $.ajax() call so maybe defining the success function separately would allow him to use `$(this)`, or the bound function could accept an `event` parameter and he could target the link that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like stef suggested but with some minor modifications.

```
$('a#my_loader').click(function() {
  var success = function(response) {
    $(this).append(response);
  }

  $.get("items/" + $(this).attr('item_id'), success);

}
```

This assumes that the `id` of the object you're targeting is stored in an attribute of your link known as `item_id`

Of course, you might want to check whether or not that html is already there before you make the AJAX call so that you don't make the call and append the partial twice.